# Redux-form validation for different submit type

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

Is it possible to have redux-form validation validate differently based on which submit button was clicked?

Like if I 'submit' a form run a full validation, but if I 'save' a form then only run a partial check?

So far, I haven't seen anything like this or a way to tell in the `validate` function. Using sync validation

```
function validate(values, props) {
   //handle validation
   //Check what type of validation to handle
}

<Button onClick={handleSubmit(this.props.save.bind(this))}>Save</Button>
<Button onClick={handleSubmit(this.props.submit.bind(this))}>Submit</Button>
```

Edit: I found [this thread](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form/issues/2511) which may better describe what I mean. But no solution there.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to dispatch a different action, or have your different onClick handlers set some flag which the `onSubmit` event handler can respond to.

Which means instead of relying on redux-form's [Form](https://redux-form.com/7.0.4/docs/api/form.md/), leverage react's `form` and handle the logic, [see](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/forms.html#controlled-components) for an example `handleSubmit`.

Comment: I'm not using the `Form` wrapper from redux-forms. And I am dispatching a different action (`save` vs `submit` in my case) for each button, the problem is the validation. `handleSubmit` is part of redux-forms

Comment: @John, you could do something where you set up some conventional validation system, but instead of having it be a submit button, you could make it a next button which would take the user to another page where the user can review what they submitted before they do a final submit. Let me know if this is even remotely in the ballpark of what you need. Otherwise, one button for partial and another for full validation is not something I would know of off the top of my head.